# Media keys won't work with iTunes after spotify starts automatically

Tags: itunes, spotify, media-keys

I have Spotify set to start with Windows, but not iTunes. Right now I would like to use the media keys with iTunes. I closed Spotify and restarted iTunes, but the keys still don't do anything.

Apart from changing the startup programs and/or restarting my computer, is there anything I can do to get the media keys to control iTunes?

Comment: Did you close the Spotify window or quit the program?

Comment: @ChristopherChipps, Exited the program and stopped any related processes.

Comment: Is this a media keys d/l you're using to control iTunes such as this http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/iTunes-Media-Keys.shtml

Comment: @ChristopherChipps, No, it normally just works :)

Answer (score 2):

I ended the itype.exe process with task manager and the media keys are working with iTunes again!